# Have difficulty implementing cwt in Python. I created a simple example for the sake of discussion

Tags: python

To understand wavelets; I tried to go over a "simple" example. I am trying to apply a Morlet wavelet for a sine signal (like 10Hz), and I do not know what scale (range) should correspond to the frequency. In the examples below, I used three different scales (different in ranges) and got different results. I assumed we needed to see an almost fixed scale in the scalogram for a fixed frequency. I am a little confused here;

```
npnts=500

time=np.linspace(0,1,npnts)

signal=np.sin(2*np.pi*10*time)

dt=time[2]-time[1]

scales =np.arange(1,32)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(8,6))

ax[0].plot(time,signal)

ax[0].set_ylabel('Intensity (a.u.)')

ax[0].set_xlabel('Time(s)')

wavelet='morl'

coeff, freq = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, wavelet)

ax[1].imshow(abs(coeff),extent=[time[0],time[-1],np.min(scales),np.max(scales)],cmap='jet',\

        vmax=np.real(coeff).max(),vmin=-abs(coeff).max(),aspect='auto')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[scales=np.arange(1,32)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJKDg.png)

[scales=np.arange(1,64)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga34k.png)

[scales=np.arange(1,128)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VjL6.png)

any ideas how to proper use cwt?

I tried a simple examples and experiment over scale range

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

Just take a look at the `freq` output by `coeff, freq = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, wavelet)` (which by the way are equal to those output by `pywt.scale2frequency('morl', scales)`). These are *normalized* frequencies, which means that you need to multiply them by your sampling frequency (500Hz) to turn them into actual frequencies.

For `scales = np.arange(1,32)`, `freq*npnts` returns:

```
array([406.25      , 203.125     , 135.41666667, 101.5625    ,
        81.25      ,  67.70833333,  58.03571429,  50.78125   ,
        45.13888889,  40.625     ,  36.93181818,  33.85416667,
        31.25      ,  29.01785714,  27.08333333,  25.390625  ,
        23.89705882,  22.56944444,  21.38157895,  20.3125    ,
        19.3452381 ,  18.46590909,  17.66304348,  16.92708333,
        16.25      ,  15.625     ,  15.0462963 ,  14.50892857,
        14.00862069,  13.54166667,  13.10483871])
```

13.10 > 10: the smallest frequency contained in your decomposed signal is higher than the central frequency of your sinusoid. This means that this decomposition may not be appropriate to analyze your input signal.

Now for `scales =np.arange(1,64)`, `freq*npnts` returns:

```
array([406.25      , 203.125     , 135.41666667, 101.5625    ,
        81.25      ,  67.70833333,  58.03571429,  50.78125   ,
        45.13888889,  40.625     ,  36.93181818,  33.85416667,
        31.25      ,  29.01785714,  27.08333333,  25.390625  ,
        23.89705882,  22.56944444,  21.38157895,  20.3125    ,
        19.3452381 ,  18.46590909,  17.66304348,  16.92708333,
        16.25      ,  15.625     ,  15.0462963 ,  14.50892857,
        14.00862069,  13.54166667,  13.10483871,  12.6953125 ,
        12.31060606,  11.94852941,  11.60714286,  11.28472222,
        10.97972973,  10.69078947,  10.41666667,  10.15625   ,
         9.90853659,   9.67261905,   9.44767442,   9.23295455,
         9.02777778,   8.83152174,   8.64361702,   8.46354167,
         8.29081633,   8.125     ,   7.96568627,   7.8125    ,
         7.66509434,   7.52314815,   7.38636364,   7.25446429,
         7.12719298,   7.00431034,   6.88559322,   6.77083333,
         6.65983607,   6.55241935,   6.4484127 ])
```

The 24th scale correspond to 10.15625, which is pretty close to the frequency of your input sinusoid. Indeed, if you draw a horizontal line at this scale, it coincides with the maximum energy seen in the decomposed signal:

[image]

I leave it to you to follow the same reasoning for the `np.arange(1,128)` decomposition.